# Select rows in sql if list is a subset of another list

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subset

I have two many-to-many mapping table between `Books-Community` and `Books-User`.
How can I get all the communities which ALL of it's books exist in the user's books as I pass `UserId` to the stored procedure?

User Books Table

```
[UserId]----------------------------[BookId]

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----27

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----28

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----35

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----36

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----40

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----41

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----56

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----67

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----88

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----103

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----104

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----155

fd95eff5-394e-4d51-b1af-46723268485f----156
```

BooksCommunityMap

```
[BookId]-----[CommunityId]

29-----------23

30-----------23

32-----------23

34-----------23

35-----------23

36-----------23
```

I want to select all the communities that all of it's books exists in the user's books

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited

Comment: you simply have inverted question...

Comment: @RuslanK. sorry for this confusion, i actually want to get communities based on user's books

Comment: @RuslanK. i have edited the question, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH cte as
(
     SELECT UserID, CASE WHEN BookId IN (SELECT Id From @incomingTableValuedVariable) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as NoBook
     FROM MAPTABLE 
),
cte2 as
(
     SELECT UserID, MAX(NOBook) as NoBook
     FROM cte 
     GROUP BY UserId
)
SELECT UserID
FROM cte2
WHERE NoBook = 0;
```

Comment: Have you tried your query? It shows `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.` error.

Comment: @gofr1 no, I edited the answer

Comment: @RuslanK. It gives me the following error 
"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."
I tried to add a semicolon but the error still the same

Comment: @Anas AL-zghoul, this query is not answer anymore to you edited question.
I've added semicolon to query.

Comment: @RuslanK. Thank you so much, it is working perfectly, i just had to switch the columns since i changed the question.

Comment: @Anas AL-zghoul, you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Here you can reed about [using a Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). I give you an example of query to get what you need:

```
DECLARE @tvv TABLE (id int)

INSERT INTO @tvv VALUES
(1),
(2)

;WITH users_books AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),
(1,2),(2,2),(3,3),
(1,3),(2,3),(3,5),
(1,4),(2,4),(3,7),
      (2,5),(3,8),
      (2,6),(3,9)
) as t (UserID, BookID)
)

SELECT UserID
FROM users_books u
LEFT JOIN @tvv i 
    ON i.id = u.BookID
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tvv)
```

Output:

```
UserID
-----------
1
2

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: If user have only one book (for example `bookId = 1`), he does not get in your query although `all of their books exists in the passed list `

Comment: It returns table with 1,2,3 Userid's.

Comment: Read the statement you quoted one more time - query must gets ALL userIDs which has ALL the books in passed list. `the users that's all of their books exists in the passed list`